Keypair.generate() => possible to get an existing keypair?
when we use Keypair.generate() to get a keypair, does the library checks if this address is already in use ?
Or is it only based on probability that this address doesn't exist ? (which i guess, is not the case...)
Or maybe there is something like a timestamp that make impossible to get twice the same address ?

Yes, its just random. There are so many possible addresses that you will never get the same address twice when you call the function.
Here is a funny website that shows all possible addresses with private keys. It has 1929868153955269923726183083478131797547292737984581739710086052358636024906 pages of keys: https://privatekeyfinder.io/private-keys/solana
Due to the incredible amount of possibilities its save. Its usually using the operatingsystems randomness functions. If you want to be very sure you can also use a hardware wallet.

ok thanks! i understand the probability of getting an existing address is very very low, near to impossible, but i'm surprised by the fact that it could happen.

Yes it could happen, you can try to find one solana-keygen grind --starts-with a23:1 just put the key you want to find the private key for. There is also some GPU grinders. With these you can find keys up to 6-7 digits. Everything after takes then forever again.
